# How to manipulate a parent item without having it modify children (css/react)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've been searching on Stack overflow and Google and cannot seem to find the answer I want on this so will do my best to ask the question here and hope one of you crazy smart people have an answer.

In a HTML sense, here's what I have

```
<ul>
  <li>
     item1
     <ul>
       <li>Item1-1</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item2</li>
<ul>
```

What I want to do is when I hover over Item1, I only want that particular component's background color to change. Just the parent component, and not it's children. So in this case if I highlight Item1, i do NOT want Item1-1 to highlight.

However, the problem with my code is that I can't seem to figure this out as when I hover over Item1 it also triggers a hover event on Item1-1 which causes issues :( I know my code the onMouseOver event triggers for Item1 when I hover over Item1-1 too which I'd like to not have it also change the color when that happens as well.

Here's my code that I have so far for this component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faTachometerAlt, faWrench } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { 
  ADMIN_BAR_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
  ADMIN_BAR_COLOR,
  ADMIN_ITEM_HOVER,
  ADMIN_ITEM_HOVER_LINK,
  ADMIN_MENU_ITEMS
} from './../const-variables';
import { tsConstructorType } from '@babel/types';

library.add(faTachometerAlt, faWrench);

export const AdminMenuItem = props => {  
  const StyledAdminMenuItem = styled.li`   
    .test {
      background-color: orange;
    }
  `;

  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState({one: false, two: false, three: false});
  function onHover() {        
    setIsSelected(!isSelected);   
  }

  return (
    <StyledAdminMenuItem 
      onMouseEnter={onHover}
      onMouseLeave={onHover}      
    >
      <div className={isSelected ? "" : "test" }>{props.title}</div>

      {props.children}
    </StyledAdminMenuItem>
  )
}

export const AdminMenuList = props => {  
  const StyledAdminMenuList = styled.ul`
    list-style-type:none;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    list-style-type: none;

`;

  return (
    <StyledAdminMenuList>
      {props.children}
    </StyledAdminMenuList>
  )
}

export const AdminMenu = props => {
  const StyledAdminMenu = styled.div`
  background-color: ${ADMIN_BAR_BACKGROUND_COLOR};
  color: ${ADMIN_BAR_COLOR};  
  width: 160px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%
`;

  return (
    <StyledAdminMenu>
      <AdminMenuList>
        <AdminMenuItem         
          title={"Item1"}
        >
          <AdminMenuList>
            <AdminMenuItem 
          title={"Item1-1"}          
          sub={true}
        />   
          </AdminMenuList>
          </AdminMenuItem>
         <AdminMenuItem 
          title={"Item2"}          
        />
      </AdminMenuList>
    </StyledAdminMenu>
  )
}
```

Any suggestions on this? Am I going about this in a terrible way? Is there's something better?

Answer (score 0):

The answer may be as simple as having Item1 be inside its own element.

Change your structure to:

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <div class="item1-background">item1</div>
     <ul>
       <li>Item1-1</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item2</li>
<ul>
```

and add your hover effect to that div

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting a `pointer-events: none;` on your Item-1-1 element
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events